# SSRS Report Builder 3.0, Dont want Row header to repeat on each group instance

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-grouping

I'm trying to do this using list objects. I have Product Numbers grouped by the Lots where they are produced. So within a list object for ProductNumber, there is a nested list object with the LotNumber and a tablix with all the data values directly below. THe problem is that when there are multiple lots per product, The row header (containing the column names) is going to repeat everytime rather than once per page. Is there a way around this besides using one big tablix? Still trying to find the best way to accomplish nested groups.

For example for one product it would look like this on one page.

**Product: MF7124**

Lot 0326

```
     PartNum    ContainerID  Status

     --------------------------------
     MF7124    195708       Out Of Rotation

     MF7124    17252        Out Of Rotation
```

Lot 0328

```
    Partnum  ContainerID  Status

  --------------------------------
    MF7124   17253       Out Of Rotation

    MF7124   17254        Out Of Rotation
```

Lot 0331

```
   PartNum    ContainerID  Status

  --------------------------------
    MF7124   17253       Out Of Rotation

    MF7124   17254        Out Of Rotation
```

Comment: you should post some sample data and code.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on your group header row and **Insert Row>Outside group Above**.

Play around it.

Comment: I just want the column names to not repeat on each lot instance.. How does this accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

What he means is the difference between these two;

In below picture upper row is outside of the parent group and will not repeat itself if parent group is repeating:

[image]

In below picture upper row is inside the parent group and will repeat itself if parent group is repeating:

[image]

So, you can insert rows inside/outside group, below/above. If you play around with it, you will get it right :)

[image]

Comment: The problem is not the tablix.... The issue is that the tablix is INSIDE of a grouped list object. I used lists to have a more flexible report with nested groups. The header row is not inside of a tablix group, but it is grouped by a list object. So is what im trying to accomplish not possible? Im thinking about just making text boxes for the column names that sit just outside the List object.

Comment: I thought a List is Tablix also, anyhow, yes you can use textboxes outside the list to accomplish it also. It is just that if you have a list within a list, grouping in both lists still apply the same.

Answer (score 0):

The key is as mentioned but also requires you to group and remove the grouping columns to achieve the formatting you require.

In the example shown below I removed the group columns for lot and product but kept the groups then added rows above and outside group:

[image: tablix layout]

This gives you the preview you require (with a little bit of formatting):
[image: preview]